# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\ in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I looked at the questions that matched mine; however, nothing was the same issue as mine.

I adding to a script with my directory (I am on Windows) and the output. The Exception: `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\username\\xyz\\forms\\happy-slice\n'`

The code:
`path_to_outp = r"C:\\Users\\username\\xyz\\forms\\happy-slice"` and I tried `path_to_out = "\\Users\\username\\xyz\\forms\\happy-slice"` and `\\Users\\username\\xyz\\forms\\happy-slice\\`

Before it I do have a path to go get the text file and read it and it does all that fine. It just seems to be mkdir:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
     os.mkdir(directory_path)
```

I believe it as it says with the Windows directory rules but being new to Python I have limited knowledge so far...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is there `\n` at the end?

Comment: That shows up on the console window where it displays the error. I never added it.

Comment: well that `\n` is still being registered by the program.. you should figure out why that is there and get rid of it. Have you tried `path_to_out = "C:/Users/username/xyz/forms/happy-slice"`?

Comment: Yes, does the same thing, adds the new line at end. '\n' - looking into that part now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using replace('\n', '') and worked.